# Change NSMutableURLRequest's default header

Tags: ios, nsmutableurlrequest

I need to change a default HTTP header "`Connection`" in `NSMutableURLRequest` to "close" value, instead of "keep-alive". What is the best practice to do it?

*I tried to use TCP level and create HTTP request myself + use GCDAsyncSocket. It works, but I think this solution looks not very nice.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As simple as u can think of:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[request setValue:@"close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
```

If u want to add value:

```
[request addValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
```

Comment: From Apple's documentation: "Important: The NSURLConnection class and NSURLSession classes are designed to handle various aspects of the HTTP protocol for you. As a result, you should not modify the following headers:
Authorization,
Connection, ...". Sniffer shows that even if I will change "Connection" header manually, it will back to default value "keep-alive".